# Cannot log out from iCloud to turn off Find My iPhone because the account is locked

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, accounts, find-my-iphone

I can't log out from iCloud on an iPhone 6 Plus. After I enter the password, a popup is shown saying I need to unlock the account because it's locked for security reasons.

I can use the same Apple ID on a different iPhone normally.

How can I turn off Find My iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your account has been locked for security reasons, most likely because of incorrect password attempts and changes.

According to [**this Apple support article**](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204106), you can either unlock your account at [**iforgot.apple.com**](http://iforgot.apple.com) or wait one day to get a few more attempts.

If neither of these options work for you, you can also [**contact Apple support**](https://expresslane.apple.com/GetproductgroupList.do?caller=itse&PRKEYS=PF23&category_id=SC0121&symptom_id=20193&target=solutions) and they will help you out.

Keep in mind that you will likely have to prove your identity if you contact Apple or try to unlock your account yourself, so be ready for that.

Comment: It's been about a week now and each time I try I get thesame pop up! And when I try iforgot they only say I should reset my password I don't see anything else about unlocking my accounts..and I have reset my accounts about 4 times within the week now but still.. Also my country is not listed in the Apple support so I can't contact Apple support

Comment: Pls I really really need help..

Comment: @Bill - your only option is to contact Apple support. [Check this list](https://www.apple.com/choose-your-country/) to find the country you reside in and receive support.